# Subset collection based on array of NumberInt

Tags: mongodb, subset

I am working with MongoDb for the first time.  My collection contains the following data

```
"VendorName":"ABC Realtors",
"SiteDetails":"MainSite",
"Cdays": 8,
"Year": NumberInt(2019),
"Month": "April",
"YearMon": "April_2019",
"Cluster": NumberInt(6538)
```

I am trying to subset the collection based on a list of `Cluster` items and following is my code:

```
   db.collection.find({Cluster : 6538 })
```

This prints all the records in the console

However, this does not:

```
db.collection.find({Cluster : {"$all":[6538,28]  }})
```

How can I get all records based on an array of NumberInt values from Mongodb. I am not sure if this has got to do with the uploading of data into mongodb.  I used the following steps:

```
df=pd.read_csv("/home/ubuntu/er.csv",encoding='ISO-8859-1')
records = json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records"))
col.insert_many(records)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The $all operator selects the documents where the value of a field is an array that contains all the specified elements

Your second query looks for documents whee cluster field is an array and should have both the values.

You could use `$in` in place of  `$all` which finds docs where cluster field contains one of the values.

```
db.collection.find({Cluster : {"$in":[6538,28]  }})
```

Comment: Thank you.  The `$in` also not working though.  it is not returning anything.  I am not sure if this has got to do with the way I uploaded the data. I have updated my question.

Comment: [Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zUPArwSBlSB) - can you make a reproducible scenario?. It works as in the play link. Please check and tell ne

Comment: Yes...it is working indeed.  not sure why it is not working in my case. Any further thoughts on this...I am accepting your answer anyway.

Comment: Please remove 28 from the query and try. It shouldn't be a problem. Make sure data is of type number. Make sure data is not inside a path means nested document. Make sure field name is matching exactly across all of your documents. Please add a document which is expected to be part of output but not. I ll help you also.